# Передача переменной в Input при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Есть форма, открывающаяся в модальном окне, которая будет передавать данные методом post в обработчик.

Для вызова модального окна с формой используются несколько кнопок, например, "Перезвоните", "Вызвать замерщика", и т.д. То есть, кнопок вызова много, а модальное окно - одно и то же.

В форме два input, один из которых нужен для ввода телефона, а второй - скрытый, в него должен передаваться дополнительный параметр (число), в зависимости от того, какой кнопкой вызвано данное окно.

То бишь, если нажали на кнопку "Перезвоните мне", то в скрытый input надо передать цифру 1, а если нажата кнопка "Заказать выезд замерщика" - то цифру 2.

Как сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обрабатываешь событие

```
$('#yourButton1').on('click', function() {
    //присваиваешь нужному инпуту значение
    $('#hiddenInputId').val(1);
});
```